# Almost surely statement in Williams book.

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

In Probability with Martingales (Williams) I came across the following proposition
[image]

and then they give the following contradictory example
[image]

Could someone please explain how it can be so? Also why is that in the truth set they use $\rightarrow \frac{1}{2}$ and not $= \frac{1}{2}$ when comparing each outcome?

Thank you.

Comment: The proposition applies to countable collections - what is the cardinality of $\mathcal{A}$?

Comment: @MLT $mathcal A$ is not countable! The proposition is stated for sequences.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Thank you. How do I find the cardinality of $\mathcal{A}$

Comment: @MLT: Hint: increasing sequences of integers are in correspondence with the infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Thank you. But those infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ are still countable isn't it? I mean since $\mathbb{N} $ is countable.

Comment: @MLT: The power set of $\mathbb{N}$ is uncountable...

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Thanks. I never new that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement says that for every $\omega$ there exists some $\alpha$ in $\mathcal A$ such that $\omega\notin F_\alpha$. To see that this holds, consider $N_\omega=\{n\in\mathbb N\mid\omega_n=H\}$.

- If $N_\omega$ is infinite, order it as $N_\omega=\{\nu_\omega(k)\mid k\in\mathbb N\}$ and consider $\alpha$ such that $\alpha(k)=\nu_\omega(k)$ for every $k$. Then $\omega_{\alpha(k)}=H$ for every $k$ hence $\frac1n\#\{k\leqslant n\mid\omega_{\alpha(k)}=H\}=1$ for every $n$, in particular $\omega\notin F_\alpha$.
- If $N_\omega$ is finite, consider $\alpha$ such that $\alpha(k)=k$ for every $k$. Then $\omega_{\alpha(k)}=H$ for finitely many $k$ hence $\frac1n\#\{k\leqslant n\mid\omega_{\alpha(k)}=H\}\to0$ when $n\to\infty$, in particular $\omega\notin F_\alpha$.

One sees that $\alpha$ such that $\omega\notin F_\alpha$ depends on $\omega$.

And this does not contradict the proposition in the book because $\mathcal A$ is uncountable. To see this, note that $\mathcal A$ is in bijection with $\mathbb N^\mathbb N$ through the application $\alpha\mapsto\beta$ defined by $\beta(1)=\alpha(1)$ and $\beta(n+1)=\alpha(n+1)-\alpha(n)$ for every $n$ in $\mathbb N$. Since $\mathbb N^\mathbb N$ is uncountable, this proves the claim

Comment: Thank you. I have one question. Why do you consider the $N_\omega$ finite case. I was thinking the space $\Omega$ is $\{H,T\}^{\infty}$ (I mean infinite tosses) and therefore there is a sequence with $\omega_n=H$ (and $\omega_n=T$) for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Consider the sequence $\omega=TTTTTTTTT\ldots$ defined by $\omega_n=T$ for every $n$. Then $N_\omega=\varnothing$ is finite.